# Как вставить значение переменных (вместо чисел)? Python 3 + postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, telebot

```
 cur.execute("INSERT INTO kraken_database VALUES (5555775, 777777)")
```

Comment: `cur.execute("INSERT INTO kraken_database VALUES (?, ?)", (5555775, 777777))`?

Comment: смотря какой у вас коннектор

Comment: коннектор pcycopg2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подстановка с коннектором pcycopg2:

```
values = ({'id': 1, 'name':'Vasya', 'age': 45})
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tableName(id, name, age) VALUES (%(id)s,%(name)s,%(age)s)", values)
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, никак не мог найти

Comment: @Alex Flow нет проблем )